# how not to run celery task on `python manage.py test`

Tags: django, unit-testing, celery

I have a model I am sending email and sms to user in `post_save` signal I am creating the model multiple times so it is sending email and sms multiple time.

I am planning to write new test for testing sms and email.

```
def send_activation_mail_sms(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created :
        mobile_activation = UserMobileActivation.objects.create(user=instance,randomword=randomword(50),ref=ref)
        email_activation = UserEmailActivation.objects.create(user=instance,randomword=randomword(50),ref=ref)
        url_email = "{0}view/v1/email/activation/{1}/".format(HOSTNAME,email_activation.randomword)             short_url_email = url_shortener(long_url_email)
        url_sms = "{0}view/v1/mobile/activation/{1}".format(HOSTNAME,mobile_activation.randomword) 
        app.send_task("apps.tasks.send_sms",
                      args=[TEXTLOCAL_APIKEY,mobile_activation.stockuser.user.username ,'TXTLCL','Activate your mobile here {0}'.format(url_sms)])
        app.send_task("apps.tasks.send_email",
                      args=[email_activation.user.user.email, EMAIL_VERIFICATION_SUBJECT,
                            EMAIL_VERIFICATION_TEMPLATE, {"host": HOSTNAME, "verify_email_url": url_email}])
```

I am passing `created` arg in `post_save` signal is there any way I can pass extra arg here so that while doing `python manage.py test` it will skip sending sms and email. I used versioning one way I was thinking to have different version of API for testing but as there is no `request` coming here I cannot catch `request.version` here. Please suggest.

Comment: What about not running the celery service while test?

Comment: @JPG They may queued then and send when celery is available, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, I've added one answer below. Check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially set some variable in your settings.py to identify the environment currently working on

```
# settings.py
MY_ENV = "DEVELOPMENT"
```

Then, run the celery tasks/additional scripts based on the **`MY_ENV`**

```
from django.conf import settings


def send_activation_mail_sms(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and settings.MY_ENV == "DEVELOPMENT":
        # do your stuff
```

Django provide us to override the settings configs during the testing, see the doc [**Override Settings**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings). So you could override the **`MY_ENV`** value in the test itself